# How do I disable GPU acceleration in my arch linux?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, dual-boot, gpu

I have dual boot arch linux with Windows 8. I have AMD Radeon GPU. Recently, my GPU has broken. And now, I cannot boot into my arch linux. I am able to boot into live CD, and it says: "disabling GPU acceleration"

I can also boot into Windows by disabling the GPU acceleration via device manager. I am unable to disable GPU acceleration in my linux manually.

I couldn't find the solutions in the internet. So, is there a way to disable my GPU acceleration in Arch?

Thanks

Comment: You can prevent a module from being loaded by passing ``modprobe.blacklist=KO_NAME`` on the kernel command line. After the first boot, blacklist it permanently using ``modprobe.d(5)``. Since you’re using Arch, you may have to adjust your ``mkinitcpio.conf(5)`` as well, cf. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/kernel_modules#Blacklisting

Comment: I tried `blacklist fglrx`, `blacklist radeon`, `alias radeon off`, and `alias lbm-radeon off` in blacklist.conf as suggested in [askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/457391/radeon-ring-0-test-failed-on-boot-ubuntu-14-04). But this led to `fatal server error: (EE) Cannot run in framebuffer mode...` error while starting X server.

Comment: It worked after loading radeon module. Thanks!!